# How to make an Icon to have two kinds of Colors in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am building a flutter application. and I wanted to make an icon to have two colors. green and red. but I can only make either green or red.
how can I achieve an icon as the following image.[this image refresh icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z7Ab.png) The following code only changes to the whole red

```
Icon(
    Icons.cached,
    color: Colors.red,
   )
```

Comment: I think it's either a custom icon or there is a gradient applied to the icon. Which you can check out here [Add gradient to flutter icon](https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/117e7fffd283c34c5078a93330504b9f)

Comment: I could use svg icons instead

Comment: That's not gonna be an icon, you can use `Image` or alike.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Instead, I recommend you to use Flutter SVG package and make your icons SVG. with desired colors.

flutter_svg package [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

Answer (score 0):

You can.

Split the icon into two separate icons and layer them on top of each other in a stack

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Icon(
      MyIconSet.background_refresh,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Icon(
      MyIconSet.foreground_refresh,
      color: Colors.green,
    )
  ],
),
```